# Python code to produce C++14 hex integer literal with ticks

Tags: code-golf, python, hexadecimal

> tl;dr? See bottom for **The Competition**

### Integer literals

While programming, the 64-bit hexadecimal literal `0x123456789abcdefL` is difficult to gauge the size of. I find myself mentally grouping digits from the right by fours to see that it's 15 digits' worth.

Python PEP 515 allows you to express the above literal, inside code, as `0x123_4567_89ab_cdefL`. If you prefer binary, then it's even more invaluable: `0b1_0010_0011_0100_0101_0110_0111_1000_1001_1010_1011_1100_1101_1110_1111L`

### String representations

Python can also convert an integer into strings with spacing characters, as follows:

```py
'{:#_b}'.format(81985529216486895L)
'{:#_x}'.format(81985529216486895L)
'{:,}'.format(81985529216486895L)
```

The first two produce what's shown above (although without the `L` suffix), while the last will produce

```py
"81,985,529,216,486,895"
```

> Although with PEP 515, they would be better expressed as:
>
> ```
> '{:#_b}'.format(81_985_529_216_486_895L)
> '{:#_x}'.format(81_985_529_216_486_895L)
> '{:,}'.format(81_985_529_216_486_895L)
> ```

Note, though, the following:

- `'_'` is only legal for binary and hexadecimal strings - and Python will insert them every four characters (from the right);
- `','` is only legal for decimal strings - and Python will insert them every three characters (from the right);
- No other separator characters are allowed.

---

### Enough with the Python syntax lesson; on to C++!

C++14 also allows separators inside an integer literal to allow grouping, much like the above. Only (of course) it's a different character: the tick (single quote `'`). So the above literals would be:

```
0b1'0010'0011'0100'0101'0110'0111'1000'1001'1010'1011'1100'1101'1110'1111uL
0x123'4567'89ab'cdefuL
81'985'529'216'486'895uL
```

Python is often used to machine-generate C/C++ code, because it's so easy to do! But there's no native Python way to generate these new 'tick'-based identifiers - `.format()` can only use `_`. So, here's some code that I wrote to do it:

```py
# Hex function with tick marks
def HexTicks(num) :
  # Convert to hex (without leading 0x - yet)
  s = '{:x}'.format(num)
  # Insert tick marks
  for i in range(len(s)-4, 0, -4) :
    s = s[:i] + "'" + s[i:]
  # Return the result
  return "0x" + s + "uLL"
```

### The Competition

> Sorry @ASCII-only !

Write a Python 2.7.3 expression or lambda, smaller than the above function (not including whitespace or comments), that:

1. Takes any non-negative integer;
2. Produces the correct hexadecimal string for that integer;
3. With a leading `0x` and trailing `uLL`;
4. No leading zeroes as part of the hex number;
5. With tick marks (`'`) every four digits, counting backwards from the right;
6. No tick mark straight after the `0x`.

#### ILLEGAL

```
0x0uLL       # If integer was anything other than zero (2.)
12'3456      # No 0x or uLL (3.)
0x0'1234uLL  # Leading zero (4.)
0x12'345uLL  # Not grouped by four (5.)
0x'1234uLL   # Tick mark before hex number (6.)
```

#### Bonuses

A. Can be easily modified to produce capital hex letters - but not the `0x` or `uLL` parts;

> Note that `.format()` allows `'{:_X}'` to capitalise the hex characters - but `'{:#_X}'` will capitalise the `0X` too

B. An extra `digits` parameter that **will** add leading zeros to that number of digits (not resultant characters; just hex digits) - unless it's already got that many.

> For example: `HexTick(0x1234,6)` would produce `"0x00'1234uLL"`

Comment: I'd advise against restricting the language here, and imposing a maximum size limit for that matter. Also, bonuses are very, _very_ frowned because there is no objective best way to score them - in fact, in your case they provide no bonus and therefore will never be done in a seriously competing answer.

Comment: Also, if you _do_ stick with this, _please_ specify Python version...

Comment: What are the bonuses worth? Please give them a value.

Comment: Hi and welcome to PPCG! You seem to have put a lot of effort into understanding the quality and precision we demand from challenge writers, and for that I'd like to say thank you. However, this challenge is rather out of "culture" for this site. There are quite a few points of contention that I think the community will have, so I'd like to direct you to the [sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2140/31625) where you could receive feedback before posting to the main site. Good luck :)

Comment: [39 bytes :P](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSHPKk2pOs9KOb6ittTHR0mvKLUgJzE5VUMpXklHSV1J839BUWZeiUaahoWhpYWpqZGlkaGZiYWZhaWppuZ/AA)

Comment: [both bonuses, 55](https://tio.run/##BcFtCkAwGADgq@j9Y9N8bEybcgNHUBqzqJkliuTs8zz@OZfdlcG0fbBqG7WKHNGNgeJ@XVO8SCc8pTjPq2@4v6vrIDtmb9U0IxiAQAw4@GN1JzJIUCk4Z5LRuhK1kJyUDOPwAw)

Comment: @ASCII-only I *really* liked the `(d*5-1)//4` - that's using your math! But D'oh! I fully intended on specifying Python version - and it slipped my mind while I was dreaming up potential loopholes. (Simply `"0x0uLL"` would have passed two minutes before I hit "Submit"!)

Comment: Oops, deleted my comment when you were writing a reply :/

Comment: [wip, 73](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSHPSsmgQrW41MdHSTVdQ0m1Qkk1T5Mr3RYqXWxVHG1iFZuYl6KQrlEcbaVrEqupraSupF0crQsUzy9SKP5fUJSZV6KRpmFhaGlhampkaWRoZmJhZmFpqqn5HwA)

Comment: @ASCII-only Why not post as answers?

Comment: @tsh The first two are in the wrong language, the third is WIP :P

Comment: Why is it limited to Python? Can you change the requirement so that we can provide answers in other languages?

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>68</s> 65 bytes

-3 bytes for both thanks to [tsh](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/44718/tsh)

```python
lambda n:"0x"+re.sub("(?!^)(?=(....)+u)","'","%xuLL"%n)
import re
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSHPSsmgQkm7KFWvuDRJQ0nDXjFOU8PeVkMPCDS1SzWVdJTUgVi1otTHR0k1T5MrM7cgv6hEoSj1f0FRZl6JRpqGhaGlhampkaWRoZmJhZmFpamm5n8A)

#### Eligible for both bonuses, <s>76</s> 73 bytes

```python
lambda x,d:"0x"+re.sub("(?!^)(?=(....)+u)","'","%%0%dxuLL"%d%x)
import re
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcNhCoMgFADg/ztFeyB7jyTKzdAgukBHGIPComCVmII7veuDz/78cuwize07fYdtNEMWuWmgjJC7qTjDiIDd/UPYtVhcKA8EHB5XxkpmYuh7YIZFuq2bPZzP3JSsW3ePM6pKKymFFlX9UrXSkj8FUfoD)

Comment: Use `import re` and `re.sub` would save bytes.

Comment: Alternative for the same cost: `lambda n:re.sub("(?<!x)(?=([^x]{4})+u)","'","%#xuLL"%n)`